# Superconductor Cube levitating in Vertical magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, superconductivity

Suppose there's a Magnetic field in vertical direction and we hold and release a superconductor cube so experimentally it is seen that the cube floats/hovers in the same orientation as it was released but how can we prove it on paper by calculating the force on surface currents?

And if we release a rotating ball superconductor so after sometime it will levitate as it was rotating initially or will just levitate without rotating?

Also if it keeps rotating the angular vel will change or not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.